# Какой функцией можно заменить mysql_result()?

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Добрый вечер. Сейчас перевожу один проект с `MySQL` на `MySQLi` и возник такой вопрос. Есть ли абсолютная замена функции `mysql_result()` в `PHP`?

```
return mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Что обозначает ноль не совсем понятно?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от того, как хотите получить результат можно использовать:

```
mysqli_fetch_array() 
mysqli_fetch_assoc()
mysqli_fetch_object()
mysqli_fetch_row()
```

Не знаю ООП или нет вы используете, но если не ООП, то подправите

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query)
$row = $result->fetch_row();
return $row;
```

Если Вам нужно заменить скажем

```
mysql_result($result,20);
```

То нужно переместить указатель на новую запись и воспользоваться вышеприведеным примером для mysqli

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$result->data_seek(20);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
return $row;
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Просто код не я писал, я только занимаюсь рефакторингом...

Comment: Обновил ответ. 0 это какую запись взять. Еще чуть подправил, ввел в заблуждение с индексом. fetch_row уже выбирает первую запись

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать!